Induced map of a GIT quotient map
Let $X$ be a smooth variety, $G$ a connected reductive group, and there is a $G$-linearlisatioin of a line bundle $L$.
Let us consider $p:X^{ss}(L)\rightarrow X/\!\!/_LG$, which is the GIT quotient map defined by Mumford.
Here,  $X^{ss}(L)$ (resp. $X^s(L)$) denotes the set of semistable points (resp. stable points).
Then I think that for any closed $G$-stable subset $W$ in $X^{ss}(L)$, $p(W)$ is closed in $X/\!\!/_LG$.
My question is the following. For a closed $G$-stable subset $W$ in $X^{ss}(L)$,
Is the map $f: W/\!\!/_L G\rightarrow X/\!\!/_LG$ a closed immersion? Or is this map proper?
(Let us assume that $X^{ss}(L)=X^s(L)$ if necessary.)
I think that there is a similar question for the stack case, cf. MO.

Consider when $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is affine, and $W=\mathrm{Spec}(A/I)$ for $I\subseteq A$ an $G$-invariant ideal. Then $W//_LG\to X//LG$ corresponds to $A^G\to (A/I)^G\cong A^G/I^G$. The isomorphism holds if $G$ is linearly reductive. For general reductive groups, the affine scheme needs further refinement.

Thank you for your comment! How about if we consider an arbitrary algebraic variety $X$?

Since $X^{ss}$ is covered by invariant affine open subschemes, and closed immersions are local properties, I think we can simply glue the affine cases to general situation, in other words, we can decompose the general case to affine cases.

@DisplayName I appreciate your comment! This is very helpful. I am so sorry, but maybe do you have a reference about $X^{ss}$ is covered by invariant affine open subschemes? Your statement is very interesting to me.

Theorem 1.10 and its proof of MFK's Geometric Invariant Theory would be a good reference. In the book the definition of $X^{ss}$ requires the affine condition. In many other literature, $X$ is projective with ample linearization $L$, then $X^{ss}$ is the union of $X_s={s\ne0}$ for $s\in \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}_+}\Gamma(X,L^n)^G$, and $X_s$ is affine.

@DisplayName I appreciate your very good comment! I will read that book carefully. Thank you very much :)
